# Python does not find Modules installed by easy_install after dist-upgrade to Wheezy

Tags: python, python-2.7, debian, trac, easy-install

I had a Debian Squeeze system, with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/srv/trac/hooks/trac-post-commit-hook -p "/srv/trac" -r "$2"
```

After upgrade to Wheezy, the script failed with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/trac/hooks/trac-post-commit-hook", line 106, in <module>
    from trac.env import open_environment
ImportError: No module named trac.env
```

I installed the modules (Trac and others) again with `easy_install`, but that didn't solve the problem. However, this hack worked:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.7.egg"
/srv/trac/hooks/trac-post-commit-hook -p "/srv/trac" -r "$2"
```

WSGI has the same problem, and I was not able to fix it yet.

What's wrong here? How can I avoid this evil hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a problem with python search path when upgrading from Squeeze to Wheezy. You can try to [debug sys.path](https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path) to find if there is any problem. You should also check easy-install.pth to modify the site installed package.

I highly recommend to use [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to manage python packages, so you won't have python path problem or package conflict when you move across machines or operation systems.

Comment: Thanks, `Trac-0.12-py2.7.egg` was not in `sys.path`. Adding it to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy-install.pth` solved the problem.